# getInsitutions failing on new user

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

In the .NetAggCatSample app, I've found that calling getInstitutions with an existing user context seems to work fine, but for new users, I'm getting an exceptions (message = "forbidden").

Could this be due to running into the max user limit in Dev mode (which I am in)?

Also, which API call actually creates the user at Intuit?

Comment: Any API call after retrieving OAuth tokens from the SAML assertion will create the user in the system.  As you mentioned, you are most likely getting the 403 error because you are at your max customer limit.  Please enable logging and post the response XML from the call that returns a 403: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0020_Aggregation_Categorization_Apps/DevKits/0250.NET_AggCat_DevKit_1.0/0006_Logging#Request_and_Response_Log

Answer (score 1):

To add the answer,

Any API call after retrieving OAuth tokens from the SAML assertion will create the user in the system. As you mentioned, you are most likely getting the 403 error because you are at your max customer limit. Please enable logging and post the response XML from the call that returns a 403:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0020_Aggregation_Categorization_Apps/DevKits/0250.NET_AggCat_DevKit_1.0/0006_Logging#Request_and_Response_Log

thanks
Jarred